# What is the name of a circular grid?

Tags: geometry

If this is a grid

[image]

What do you call it when it's a circle like this?

[image]

Excuse the poor artwork.

Comment: I think its called a radial grid

Comment: http://www.graphicxtras.com/polar-grid-tool-illustrator.htm is nice !